# how to fetch Handover IP of our link

Tags: routing, switch

there is a link between two places and I want to have handover IP through my switches can anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: What is handover IP? There are currently two versions of IP: IPv4 and IPv6. You need to explain what you mean.

Comment: Can you provide other details related to the switch? Is it Cisco, Juniper, HP...?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for failover not handover.

For fail over both routers can have the same IP as long as the secondary is set to Active = no - If both show the same IP you would have conflict. All you would need after that is a heart beat link, and have the secondary router kick in if the first goes offline.

As for method, it would greatly depend on the router, and setup protocols of the routers.